# Turn text/PDF into objects in a 3D world you can walk through first person

Tags: pdf, data-visualization, 3d, plain-text

Imagine the text of a book floating in the air as 3D objects (in the same format/order as the original text).

Imagine you're Superman and you're flying around the text to view it. You can fly far away to view more text at once or fly closer to see more. You can grab/pick up letters or words and move around in them if you decide to fly in the text. You could run inside an O and run around in circles inside of it like Sonic the Hedgehog.

Is there a program/game that allows the user to create custom levels such that you input either a PDF or some plain text and let you fly around through the text as a first person character?

Specifications for what I have

- Windows 10 Tablet
- I also have a Samsung Android phone
- Program/game should be free
- Hopefully something that requires no knowledge of programming or computers

There's no practical application to this.

Comment: And maybe some way to shoot/highlight the words or a paragraph that will make the program read the words aloud and highlight them as they are being read